# Error when connecting to FTP using apache commons

Tags: java, android, file, permissions, ftp

I am using apache common library for connecting to FTP with Android app.
Now I want to upload a file from internal storage to FTP server and I get this reply from getReplyString() method.

And I get this msg

553 Can't open that file: Permission denied

//Write file to the internal storage

```
String path = "/sdcard/";
    File file = new File(path, fileName);
    FileOutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        stream.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Read the file from resources folder.

    try {
        File file1 = new File(path, fileName);
        Log.d("path",file1.getPath());
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream (file1.getPath()));
        client.connect(FTPHost);
        client.login(FTPUserName, FTPPassword);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        // Store file to server

        Log.d("reply",client.getReplyString());
        boolean res = client.storeFile("/"+fileName, in);
        Log.d("reply",client.getReplyString());
        Log.d("result",res+"");
        client.logout();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have write access to the root directory (/) in remote?  Were you able to try the FTP on command line?

Comment: Trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization; grammar. // https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/18967590

Comment: Excuse me because of my delay the permission in root directory was the problem tnx Jerin Joseph